# Printing mathematical fraction in C++

Tags: c++

I want that the program will print 0.75 and the output is 300

```
int a=300;
int b=400;
double c=a%b;
printf("%lf\n",c)
```

The program prints "300" and i want that it will print 0.75.
need help pleass

Comment: try `double c = (float)a/b;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % symbol is for modulus not division.

As your two variables a & b are both integers, the result you will get from a division will also be an integer, which in the case of 300 / 400 is zero.

What you need to do is force one of those variables to be a float or double.  You could either do this when you defined them or cast one to be a double or a float.

So your code becomes :

```
int a=300;
int b=400;
double c = (double) a/b;
printf("%lf\n",c)
```

Informing the compiler that you actually want to perform a floating point division instead of an integer based one.